# How can I put a symbol $15^{th}$ inside \thead table?

Tags: tables, macros, tabularx

How can I put a symbol $15^{th}$ inside \thead table?

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{} 
}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Percentiles}} \\
\cmidrule{3-5} 
  & {\thead{N}}
  & {\thead{25^{th}}}
  & {\thead{50^{th}} (Median)}
    & {\thead{75^{th}}} \\
\midrule
12.220 &  10 & 34.44 & 33.24 & 100.00 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I am having error:
[image]

Comment: The error message is Overflow trying to tell you that `^` forced it into math mode, but you hadn't started math mode with `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\thead{{\textbf{Statistic 1\textsuperscript{st}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!